# React code snippet does not run in repl.it

Tags: reactjs, replit

I am unable to run this [React code snippet](https://replit.com/@recrec/useRef-no-rerender#src/App.js) using repl.it.

Can you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Even though your issue is occurring on an external site it is still a good idea to include the code and some specific about your environment in you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any JavaScript files that contain React templates need to use the `.jsx` file extension, and then need to import React.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const count = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    count.current = count.current + 1;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h1>Render Count: {count.current}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I import `App.jsx` into `main.jsx` and yet it doesn't seem to work in the repl.it environment when i launch https://useRef-no-rerender.recrec.repl.co

Comment: Check your JavaScript console. There is an error because you are missing `import React from 'react';` in your App.jsx file.

Comment: Got it. It works.